# Subtracting two columns to form a new column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subtraction

My df looks like this;

```
            no_1  no_2  no_3
2022-10-12  4     5     53
2022-10-13  48    4     34
2022-10-14  0     43    93
2022-10-15  0     3     43
.
.
.
2022-10-22  8     34    4
```

I'm simply trying to add a new column which the the value when you subtract two other columns which should be easy but for some reason keeps failing.

I have the following;

```
no_data['no_4'] = no_data['no_3'] - no_data['no_1']
```

but keep getting the error..

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I'm afraid my trouble-shooting hasn't helped me with this so any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: Oh.. I really don't understand why it keeps failing..

Comment: If you are using IDE like Jupiter try to restart it.

Comment: run `no_data.info()` & let me know what output you got?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption Mostly `MultiIndex` issue try re assigning column names & Let me know if it worked

```
no_data.columns=['no_1', 'no_2', 'no_3']
no_data['no_4'] = no_data['no_3'] - no_data['no_1']
```